# how to handover *args to pathos' amap

Tags: python, pathos

I have the following problem: I would like to use a amap from pathos.multiprocessing.

```
import pathos as pt

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def f(self, a, b, c):
        return a + b + c

    def g(self):  
        pool = pt.multiprocessing.ProcessPool()
        def _h(a, b, c):
            k = self.f(a, b, c)
            return k/2
        result = [pool.amap(_h, (i, j, k)) for i in range(3) for j in range(5) for k in range(7)]
        return result

a = Foo()
b = a.g()
b[0].get()
```

It is necessary to have these two function f and g although I could do everything within f.

If I run this code I get that g expects 3 arguments but one was given.

```
TypeError: _h() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't have pathos and can't find its docs, but it seems like you could either rewrite `_h` to take a tuple or see if pathos has a `starmap` analogue.

Comment: ...wait, you're passing a single tuple to amap, not a list of tuples. That seems completely wrong; something with `map` in the name should take an iterable to map the function over, not a single argument tuple.

Comment: @user2357112 thx for your comment. you can find pathos here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos . about your second comment. even if I use a list of tuple it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `amap` defined as:

```
149     def amap(self, f, *args, **kwds): # register a callback ?
...
152         return _pool.map_async(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
```

there is an usage example in source code:

```
pool.amap(pow, [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])
```

given `l` as your input:

```
l = [(i, j, k) for i in range(3) for j in range(5) for k in range(7)]
```

you could transpose your input:

```
results = pool.amap(_h, *map(list, zip(*l)))
```

or use a generator, which is supposed to be faster:

```
def getter(n):
    for e in l:
        yield e[n]
result = pool.amap(_h, *[getter(n) for n in range(3)])
```

or, use `apipe` api instead:

```
results = [pool.apipe(_h, l)]
```

of course, you could make input more suitable with its interface once you get the idea. but why not just use `multiprocessing.pool.async_apply` instead, its interface is exactly as you expected at first.

Comment: +1. many thanks for your answer. I will wait until I accept an answer and distribute the bounty to leave it open for others as well. One question: Is there a more efficient way to build inputs `l` ?

Comment: @math you may fond with the generator solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know it looks strange, however I like the idea of passing data as iterable in pathos.

To achieve what you are looking for you must pass the elements as a separate iterable item. Here is an example:

```
def g(self):  
    pool = pt.multiprocessing.ProcessPool()
    def _h(a, b, c):
        k = self.f(a, b, c)
        return k/2
    result = [pool.amap(_h, (i,),( j,),(k,))) for i in range(3) for j in range(5) for k in range(7)]
    return result
```

Please notice the strange way of passing parameters here: `pool.amap(_h, (i,),( j,),(k,))`

You can get an idea why it is done so if you trace [_pool.map_async(star(f), zip(*args))](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/blob/008513f7d9db8c7a877df437b9e9c742aef717bf/pathos/multiprocessing.py#L152) call a bit.

In general, you might want to call your function multiple times with different parameters. Here is what I've done to demonstrate it:

```
def g(self):  
    pool = pt.multiprocessing.ProcessPool()
    def _h(a, b, c):
        print('a: {0} b: {1}. c: {2}'.format(a, b, c))
        k = self.f(a, b, c)
        return k/2
    return [pool.amap(_h, (1,4), (2,5), (3,6))]
```

Even when I called function once explicitly it got executed twice. 
Output:

```
a: 1 b: 2. c: 3
a: 4 b: 5. c: 6
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would be happy to know a reason :(

Comment: +1 one. Thanks for your answer. I will keep the bounty open for a moment. But it looks like this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Sure, I would be happy to see other examples. @georgexsh's is pretty good one.

Comment: @TarasMatsyk maybe one question: in your second example with calling the function multiple times with different parameters. Is it guaranteed that results are the same order as the inputs. I.e. does the first value in the solution always correspond to the input triple (1, 2, 3) ?

Comment: Yes, it should be, that is what python [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function does in map_async call